# HikariCp is not able to connect to DB2 Database

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, db2, hikaricp

When i am trying to connect to DB2 using using Spring Boot 2.2.1. HikariCP Pool  is not able to make a successful connection but at the same time it is connecting to JDBC.

Adding clue:
When i tried to put wrong password it gave me authentication error.

Enviroments:

1. HikariCP version: 3.4.1
2. JDK version     : 1.8.0_111
3. Database        : DB2
4. Driver version  : 11.5
5. Spring boot Version : 2.2.1

Below are error logs

```
    2019-11-28 16:16:38.098  INFO 10144 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-11-28 16:16:38.196  INFO 10144 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-11-28 16:16:38.197  INFO 10144 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.27]
2019-11-28 16:16:38.799  INFO 10144 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-11-28 16:16:38.799  INFO 10144 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 8427 ms
2019-11-28 16:16:39.866  WARN 10144 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : HikariPool-1 - maxLifetime is less than 30000ms, setting to default 1800000ms.
2019-11-28 16:16:39.866  INFO 10144 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2019-11-28 16:16:42.035  INFO 10144 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Driver does not support get/set network timeout for connections. ([jcc][10181][13991][4.26.14] Method getNetworkTimeout is not supported. ERRORCODE=-4450, SQLSTATE=0A504)
2019-11-28 16:16:42.036 ERROR 10144 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Failed to execute isValid() for connection, configure connection test query ([jcc][1079][11955][4.26.14] Feature not supported: timeout in isValid is not supported. ERRORCODE=-4450, SQLSTATE=0A504).
2019-11-28 16:16:42.320 ERROR 10144 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Error thrown while acquiring connection from data source

com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlFeatureNotSupportedException: [jcc][1079][11955][4.26.14] Feature not supported: timeout in isValid is not supported. ERRORCODE=-4450, SQLSTATE=0A504
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.b7.a(b7.java:804) ~[jcc-11.5.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.b7.a(b7.java:66) ~[jcc-11.5.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.b7.a(b7.java:116) ~[jcc-11.5.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.Connection.isValidX(Connection.java:4158) ~[jcc-11.5.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.Connection.isValid(Connection.java:7702) ~[jcc-11.5.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.checkValidationSupport(PoolBase.java:450) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.checkDriverSupport(PoolBase.java:433) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.setupConnection(PoolBase.java:402) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:355) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:473) [HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:562) [HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) [HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) [HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:158) [spring-jdbc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:116) [spring-jdbc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:79) [spring-jdbc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:324) [spring-jdbc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.isEmbedded(EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.java:120) [spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateDefaultDdlAutoProvider.getDefaultDdlAuto(HibernateDefaultDdlAutoProvider.java:42) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration.lambda$getVendorProperties$1(HibernateJpaConfiguration.java:130) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateSettings.getDdlAuto(HibernateSettings.java:41) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.determineDdlAuto(HibernateProperties.java:136) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.getAdditionalProperties(HibernateProperties.java:102) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.determineHibernateProperties(HibernateProperties.java:94) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration.getVendorProperties(HibernateJpaConfiguration.java:132) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.entityManagerFactory(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:133) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:625) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at com.alight.onelight.benefitService.BenefitServiceApplication.main(BenefitServiceApplication.java:10) ~[main/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
```

Properties files attached:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:db2:DBT1
spring.datasource.username=XXXXX
spring.datasource.password=XXXXXXX
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle= 10
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size= 10
spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime= 1000
spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit =true
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [suggested configuration](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/87):

> ```
> dataSourceClassName = com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource
> dataSource.user=test
> dataSource.password=test
> dataSource.databaseName=mydb
> dataSource.serverName=localhost
> dataSource.portNumber=50000
> dataSource.currentSchema = DB2INST1
> dataSource.driverType = 4
> ```
>
> DB2 should work just fine, have you tried specifying the `dataSourceClassName` property as `com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource`

Comment: Property file attached

Comment: @himanshu2212 add `spring.datasource.dataSourceClassName=com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource`

Comment: @himanshu2212 change value in line `spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource`

Comment: Getting below exception after changing configuration java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource cannot be cast to java.sql.Driver

Comment: Do i need to attach any file?

Answer (score 0):

As the log clearly states

> Failed to execute isValid() for connection, configure connection test query

It seems your DB2 driver isn't advanced enough to support `isValid()`, so [configure a test query](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#configuration-knobs-baby) to the connection pool (don't know what the DB2 version needs to be, something like `SELECT 1` usually). Then that query is used to determine whether the connection is valid, instead of calling `isValid()`.